# Is it possible to restore a MSSQL2005 enterprise database on aMSSQL2005 standard server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to restore a .bak-file from a MSSQL2005 enterprise server on a MSSQL2005 standard server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, should be no problem if it's a user database.  You can't restore system databases from one build to the other.